# Create an XML file with a union of all nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm processing a large XML file and generate a website from it. Currently the issue is that the build process takes too long when making a change to the code base and it's not necessary as far as testing is concerned to build the website using the entire XML. Is it possible to create an XML file that's a superset of everything within the master XML file? The idea is that the build process could use this small version of the XML file to make the process quicker.

For example here is a small example of the structure:

```
    <topic id="vehicles">
        <topic id="ford-focus">
            <title>FORD FOCUS</title>
            <body>
              <data name="isNew">true</data>        
            </body>
        </topic> 
        <topic id="vauxhall-astra">
            <title>VAUXHALL ASTRA</title>
            <data name="IsUsed">true</data> 
        </topic> 
    </topic>
```

What I'm trying to do is merge or union all the nodes so that I get the following, this is obviously a very basic example, the original feed is a lot more complicated and has multiple layers of nesting.

```
    <topic id="vehicles">
        <topic id="ford-focus">
            <title>FORD FOCUS</title>
            <body>
              <data name="isNew">true</data>
              <data name="IsUsed">true</data>                     
            </body>
        </topic> 
    </topic>
```

Comment: All depends on your preferred language or the one the website is developed in but you can merge XML files in many mainstream programming languages. In C# for example you could use Linq-to-XML (among other ways). Java will no doubt have similar functionality but I'm unaware of the ins and outs of doing this in Java. You could even write an XSL Transform but it's tedious and unwieldy (imho). Just search online for "merge two xml files [insert your desired language here]".

Comment: So what result do you want? Do you really want to mix data from different cars? Look closely: your Ford are both new and used at the same time.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Yes mixing the result if fine, you see I use the properties  isNew and isUsed on the UI so I just want to make sure both are displayed and are coming through.

Comment: You could probably convert XML to XSD and then XSD back to a sample XML. A possible first step: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0e106b9-6ea9-4c56-b7ba-3b71c05a41d4/create-xsd-from-xml-in-c?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: I don't understand. Car vauxhall-astra disappeared as a result. Is this correct?